# How to make an interactive isoslides presentation using Shiny and Rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown, ioslides

When I make a `Shiny` app in an `.Rmd` file to make an `isoslides` presentation, the app "behaves" like a static `html` page (interactivity is not possible).

For example, the following code in an `Rmd` file will produce a static `html` presentation that you can not interactively use.

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Useless App

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
        numericInput("n", "How old are you?", value = 1)
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
        
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
````

What am I missing?

Comment: do you get [this](https://i.imgur.com/DvNzXg2.png) message

Comment: @rawr I do not see any message =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is inaccurate.

For your YAML header

```
---
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---
```

To embed your shiny app (assuming it is a separate file):

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message=F, warning=FALSE}
shinyAppFile(
  "FileMyAppIsIn/app.R",
  options = list(width = "100%", height = 700)
)
``
````

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this unfortunately.

The closest thing would be to deploy your shiny app to some address,
either on the web or local, and then embed it in your slides with an iframe.

For example:

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with plot

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

## Slide with Shiny app in iframe

<iframe width = "560" height = "315" src="https://nsgrantham.shinyapps.io/tidytuesdayrocks/"></iframe>
````

[image]

If you wanted to do this with a local app, you would deploy your app in a separate R session, then grab the local address from the browser (e.g. something like: http://111.0.0.1:1234/ and paste that as the iframe source.

Comment: this is awesome! I had to open up in the browser for it to work which is absolutely fine. Just tested with a Quarto presentation too!